# Swing Dialog/Optionpane event handling: Optionpane closes parent frame in modal mode?

Tags: java, swing

In the constructor of a JFrame Mygraph i invoke some work (retrieving remote data for a graph and painting it) to be done via invokeLater in the constructor:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doWorkRunnable);
```

This is all fine, however i sometimes want to display an dialog box at the end of the process to indicate that the requested set is truncated etc:

```
JOptionPane aMsg = Meldingen.Instance().getConclusie();
JDialog aDialog = aMsg.createDialog(null, "Meldingen");

//aDialog.setModal(false);
aDialog.setVisible(true);
```

When i click 'OK' on this dialog it also closes the parent frame. When i run it in a non-modal fashion it's ok as no other frames are closed. I cannot find which mechanism in the Swing Event universe causes the unrelated JFrame Mygraph to close. Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Look at the http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html. I suppose it is that you want.

Comment: Closing a dialog will NOT close a parent JFrame. You have a problem in your code. Create a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that attempts to duplicate this problem and I'm sure will find the problem.

Comment: What happens if you specify a component as the parent component when calling `createDialog ()`?